# Socket API SocketImpl

Tags: java, sockets, documentation, javadoc

According to the Java docs for Socket the socket has an instance of a class called SocketImpl.

However if you look at that class it clearly states that SocketImpl is an abstract class.

As far i know you cannot have an instance of an abstract class! could anyone tell me what is going on here?

Link: [Socket Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)

Qoute from Docs:

> The actual work of the socket is performed by an instance of the SocketImpl class.

Link to SocketImpl class: [SocketImpl](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/SocketImpl.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual concrete object is an instance of a class which extends `SocketImpl`:

```
public class ConcreteSocketImpl extends SocketImpl {
    ... (implement all the abstract methods from SocketImpl)
}
```

And since inheritance defines an *is a* relationship, any instance of ConcreteSocketImpl *is a* SocketImpl.

That's a fundamental principle of object orientation. If you couldn't have any instance of an abstract class, abstract classes and interfaces would make no sense at all, and would be completely useless.

Comment: How does the socket create a new concrete class that extends socketimpl? according to java docs it only says it has an instance of it?

Comment: The constructor of Socket creates such an instance, using the [SocketImplFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketImplFactory.html) See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSocketImplFactory%28java.net.SocketImplFactory%29